# change packaging value in pom during delivery to ibm RTC

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml, maven-plugin, rtc

I wanted to know if we have a plugin or can we write a pre delivery script that will change the value of packaging in my pom file. I want it updated from jar to pom. Can a plugin help with this? Suggestion welcome.
 I tried-and-tested with maven profiles but do not want to go that route.

Answer (score 0):

When you deliver in RTC, all you are doing is making your file available to any repo workspace monitoring the common Stream.

If you need to make some change to a `pom.xml` (without using profiles), then it is simpler to publish (that is add, commit and deliver) as well a script which would:

- copy the `pom.xml`
- change it as you need
- use it with a `mvn -f pom-modified.xml`

The point is, as [mentioned in this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/224137/pre-deliver-procedure-enforced-by-rtcjenkins):

> There is no out of the box solution for enforcing any pre-deliver steps.

You can try and add an [RTC extension](https://jazz.net//library/article/784), as described in "[RTC: Build On Deliver Participant](https://jorgediazblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/rtc-build-on-deliver-participant/)" by [Jorge Díaz](https://jorgediazblog.wordpress.com/about/).

Comment: Can you explain or give reference what you mean by publish and script? I am kinda new to RTC.

Comment: What I understand from your reference links is that I can control post deliver using hooks.. So if all developers commit in one stream then before moving to the next stream (via Change Flow Target) the change can be made. I am looking at not updating the pom file manually.

Comment: @Jose Sorry, that was a typo. I have edited the answer.